# Trigger Button Click when Radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, when I select one of radio button (ex: id = one), and click button will be show alert ("one").
here is my code

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="one" id="one">one
<input type="radio" name="test" value="two" id="two">two
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

and my JS

```
$("#click").click(function(){
  if($('input[type="radio"]').attr('id') == 'one'){
    alert ("one")
  } else{
    alert("two")
  }
})
```

My question is why alert two is not show? any body help? thank you
http://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/gydrw291/10/

Answer (score 2):

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on `.attr`:

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually, use a looping construct...

Because your selector

```
input[type="radio"]
```

will always return a collection that contains the `#one` element in front, your `if` statement will always evaluate to `true`.

To fix it, have your selector string select only the radio button that's *selected* - so, use the `:checked` psuedo-selector as well:

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('id') == 'one') {
    alert("one")
  } else {
    alert("two")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" value="one" id="one">one
<input type="radio" name="test" value="two" id="two">two
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Comment: Oh my god, I missing for basic HTML and jquery. Thanks for help and it work @CertainPerformance